# Extract a List of Co-ordinates from a List of Complex Solutions

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

Let's say I have this list of solutions from a previous computation:

```
{
 {x -> -9.640491283722653` - 5.790987589334252` I}, 
 {x -> -9.640491283722653` + 5.790987589334252` I},
 {x ->  0.`- 14.792128645445802` I},
 {x ->  0.`+ 14.792128645445802` I},
 {x ->  9.640491283722653`- 5.790987589334252` I},
 {x ->  9.640491283722653`+ 5.790987589334252` I}
}
```

Now, how do I extract a list of coordinates from them?

Like

```
{
 {-9.640491283722653`, - 5.790987589334252`},
 {-9.640491283722653`, + 5.790987589334252`},
 {0.`,- 14.792128645445802`},
 {0.`,+ 14.792128645445802},
 {9.640491283722653`,- 5.790987589334252`},
 {9.640491283722653`,+ 5.790987589334252` }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Works nicely:

```
rules = {{x -> -9.640491283722653` - 5.790987589334252` I},
         {x -> -9.640491283722653` + 5.790987589334252` I},
         {x -> 0.` - 14.792128645445802` I}, {x -> 0.` + 14.792128645445802` I},
         {x -> 9.640491283722653` - 5.790987589334252` I},
         {x -> 9.640491283722653` + 5.790987589334252` I}};

Through[{Re, Im}[x]] /. rules
   {{-9.64049, -5.79099}, {-9.64049, 5.79099}, {0., -14.7921}, {0., 14.7921},
    {9.64049, -5.79099}, {9.64049, 5.79099}}
```

Comment: /. is a shortcut for which function ?

Comment: @The-Ever-Kid, in the interest of teaching you how to fish: highlight the `/.` in your *Mathematica* notebook and press F1.

Comment: Thanks.....BTW you learned all you know from the Docs Right ?

Comment: ...and reading [other resources](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18), and a lot of practice and trial and error.

Answer (score 3):

J. M. recommended: `Through[{Re, Im}[x]] /. rules`

I believe it is cleaner to use: `{Re@x, Im@x} /. rules`

These prove to be equivalent.

First an explanation of the replacement being done (with `/.`).  As shown in the documentation when the right-hand side of `/.` is a list of lists of [rules](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Rule.html) you get replacements for each:

```
x /. {{x -> 1}, {x -> 3}, {x -> 7}}
```

> ```
> {1, 3, 7}
> ```

`ReplaceAll` (the long form of `/.`) does not have a [Hold attribute](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HoldAll.html) so `Through[{Re, Im}[x]]` actually evaluates to `{Re[x], Im[x]}` *before* the replacements are made.  (I use `@` simply because I like to save keystrokes and reduce stacking of brackets.)

Answer (score 3):

Since V 10.1 we have `ReIm`

```
list =
  {{x -> -9.6 - 5.7 I}, {x -> -9.6 + 5.7 I}, {x -> 0. - 14.7 I}, {x -> 0. + 14.7 I}};

ReIm @@@ Values[list]
```

{{-9.6, -5.7}, {-9.6, 5.7}, {0., -14.7}, {0., 14.7}}

Answer (score 2):

Using `Cases` and `ReIm`:

```
list = {{x -> -9.6 - 5.7 I}, {x -> -9.6 + 5.7 I}, 
        {x -> 0. - 14.7 I}, {x -> 0. + 14.7 I}}; (*eldo's data*)

Cases[list, {Rule[lhs_, rhs_]} :> {Sequence @@ ReIm[rhs]}]

(*{{-9.6, -5.7}, {-9.6, 5.7}, {0., -14.7}, {0., 14.7}}*)
```

Or using `ReplaceAll` and `ReIm`:

```
list /. Rule[lhs_, rhs_] :> Sequence @@ ReIm[rhs]

(* {{-9.6, -5.7}, {-9.6, 5.7}, {0., -14.7}, {0., 14.7}}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

@rm -rf has suggested and deleted something like what I will propose, but I do find that it is the simplest one for a list of complex numbers. The other proposal is only for pedagogical reasons.

We can use a [**`Rule`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule.html)

```
Values[Flatten[list]] /. Complex[x_, y_] -> {x, y}
```

or we can use a resourccce function called [**`ThroughOperator`**](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ThroughOperator/), which is a development thanks to @Sjoerd Smit.

```
ArrayReshape[
 ResourceFunction["ThroughOperator"][{Re, Im}] /@ 
  Values[list], {Length@list, 2}]
```